# changing text of radio button for different combo-box selection in vb.net 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, radio-button

I am using visual studio 2013. I have 6 radio-buttons. I want to change their text when particular entry is selected from combo-box. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the SelectionChangeCommitted event. For example:

```
   Private Sub ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted

    If ComboBox.SelectedValue = "" Then
        Me.radiobutton.Text = ""
    End If

End Sub
```